# explain this java code please

Tags: java

In this program if I enter 10 when it says enter a value what would be the output? `num1` becomes 10, while `num2` is 6, I don't understand what `num1 = num1` mean? `10 = 10 + 2 = 12`?

I think I understood it, it takes 10 from the user, `num1` is then assigned the value of `num1 + 2`, which is 12. `num2` then becomes `num1`, `12` then `12/6 = 2`.

Output: 2

```
import java.util.*;

public class Calculate
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(system.in);
        int num1, num2;
        num2 = 6;
        System.out.print("Enter value");
        num1 = sc.nextInt();
        num1 = num1 + 2;
        num2 = num1 / num2;
        System.out.println("result = " + num2);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be the number 2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In future questions, please copy-paste (**not** retype) your exact code into your question. What you have typed here won't compile due to mission `{`, missing `"`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

It assigns the value of `num1 + 2` back to `num1`.

So yes, if `num1 = 10`, the value `12` will be stored in `num1`.

Then that will be divided by `6`, leaving `2`.

Also, it never says `num1 = num1`, you can't isolate parts of a statement like that--the statement, an assignment, is `num1 = num1 + 2`.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to understand is that `num1` does not become a fixed number (eg 10) it remains a variable. And by definition a variable varies.

when you say `x = 10` and then `x = x+1`, what really happens is something like this: `y = x + 1` and then `x = y`

Answer (score 1):

```
int num1, num2; 
num2 = 6; // Now num2 has value 6
System.out.print(Enter value"); 
num1 = sc.nextInt(); // Now num1 has value 10, which you just entered
num1 = num1 +2; // num1 is being assigned the value 10 + 2, so num1 becomes 12
num2 = num1/num2; // Now num1 = 12 and num2 = 6; 12/6 = 2
System.out.println("result = "+num2);
```

You should get an output of 2; see above comments...

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Calculate  {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(system.in);  // Whatever you read from System.in goes into the "sc" variable.
        int num1, num2;                       // num1 = 0.  num2 = 0.
        num2 = 6;                             // num2 = 6.
        System.out.print(Enter value");
        num1 = sc.nextInt();                  // Read in the next integer input and store it in num1.
        num1 = num1 +2;                       // num1 gets 2 added to it and stored back in num1.
        num2 = num1/num2;                     // num1 gets divided by num2 and the (integer) result is stored in num2.
        System.out.println("result = "+num2); // Print out the result which is stored in num2.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the equal sign `=` is an assignment operator. It evaluates the expression on the right and assigns the resulting value to the variable on the left. So if `num1` had the value `10` before the statement `num1 = num1 + 2;`, then after that statement it would have the value `12`.

Answer (score 0):

```
num1 = sc.nextInt();
num1 = num1 +2;
num2 = num1/num2;
```

In these statements, `=` is the *assignment operator*, not the equality operator. When you read it, don't say "equals", but rather "is assigned the value of":

```
num1 is assigned the value of sc.nextInt().
```

So, num1 is now 10.

```
num1 is assigned the value of num1 + 2
```

So, num1 is now 12

```
num2 is assigned the value of num1 / num2, or
num2 is assigned the value of 12 / 6
```

So, num2 is now 2.

Answer (score 0):

1. It takes number input from user.
2. Adds 2 to the number that user entered.
3. Divides this value with 6 and add result to the num2 variable.
4. Prints "result = some number" to the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
num1 = num1 +2;
```

means you are adding 2 to your num1. This can be represented as

```
num1 += 2; //which means the same as above
```

The outcome of your program will be determined by the integer division you are doing:

```
num2 = num1/num2;
```